# Can't display Array data

Tags: angular

**Hello,**  I'm sorry it's trivial question but it makes me crazy don't why I can't get data from array.

This is my Array :

[image]

This is my code to display data in HTML :

```
 <span class="candidate-list-time order-1">{{notification.date}}</span>
```

I don't know what is wrong, I allways display data that way, please any help.

Comment: <span class="candidate-list-time order-1">{{notification[0].date}}</span>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array to save notifications

```
notifications :any[]=[];
```

Change your 2D Array to 1D Array

```
this.notifications = res.map(value => value[0]);
```

So you can use the same html code

```
 <span class="candidate-list-time order-1">{{notification.date}}</span>
```